# What is the meaning of the plus (+) sign in the User section of my Git bash shell prompt?

Tags: windows, bash, shell, git, active-directory

I recently installed Bash for Windows to use Git on my office laptop with Windows 10, an OS I'm not so familiar with. When I open this bash terminal I expect the prompt would show you your username and hostname, like on Linux, for example:

```
myusername@LAPTOPNAME-COMPANYDOMAIN MINGW64 ~/current-dir $
```

Except I'm seeing something like this:

```
COMPANY+myusername@LAPTOPNAME-COMPANYDOMAIN MINGW64 ~/current-dir $
```

My question is about the first part:   'COMPANY+'.

'COMPANY' matches the part after @ of my corporate email adress. What does this mean? What's the plus sign mean? Am I logged in as two users at the same time? Is this another kind of domain or host, or something else entirely? Active Directory? And what would be the correct term to use? (Since I find googling this question rather tricky)

The output of echo $PS1 is as follows:

```
\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM\[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$
```

Thank you in advance.